# IE gradient filter doesn't respond to click event

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to have a transparent background-color and I use gradient filter as a fallback of RGBA in IE. The code is like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#bfffffff,endColorstr=#bfffffff);
```

I also want to trigger an event when the user clicks the background, but it seems like the click event doesn't get triggered after I set the filter. Everything is ok without the filter.

So is it another IE bug? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I hope you know that the IE DX filters use #AARRGGBB rather than #RRGGBBAA?

Comment: Yes I do. And the transparent effect works well. The problem is click event cannot be triggered after I apply the filter

Comment: Good, I was just making sure that you did. (It caught me unaware the first time I encountered it.) I suppose if I'd paid proper attention to the form of your question I would have seen what you were doing. I thought of exactly the same technique a couple of days ago... an interesting problem you've found with it which may save me time later if I use it!

Comment: IMO, filters are not a good way to go -- and obviously you are dealing with an older version of IE (IE 10 to be released soon) So, why not use a background image in older versions of IE only? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably related to the IE bug that makes links with transparent background no longer clickable: I came across it today. I had a link with a transparent background and display set to block: the main area of the link wasn't clickable, but a 10px border I set on it was. It seems IE also has problems with filters.

This kind of bug is discussed [here](http://haslayout.net/css/No-Transparency-Click-Bug) and [here](http://coilmedia.com/post/2010/can-not-click-or-hover-transparent-links-elements-in-internet-explorer/). The first guy's solution is to give a fake background image to the element before setting the filter. The second guy's is to give the element a background colour and set the opacity to 1%, which will make it practically invisible in IE. Hopefully you'll be able to get round it using one of these.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the deal.
Internet explorer creates the filters on a separate layer which is placed above your element and since the new graphic layer is not part of the element - which you have the click event on - there will be no event bubbling.

Recently I made a label element with a nice gradient filter for IE. Only the text can be clicked. If I analyze the label layers from the side with and without the gradient layer, then you will understand the problem.

```
without gradient filter:

------------------
 text layer
------------------
 background layer
------------------


with gradient filter:

------------------
 text layer
------------------
 gradient layer
------------------
 background layer
------------------
```

By the way, that is the reason, why you cannot put a border radius on a gradient filter too. Try it. Create an element, and style it with border radius and give it a gradient filter and run it in IE 9. No matter how you try to force the gradient to stay inside the round borders - with for example overflow:hidden -, it will never obey. Its like a separate element which is positioned absolute and right above your element to cover it up and right under the text.